# SQL query to find user using single input box

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am using core PHP. I am facing a problem when trying to find a user.

I have one Textbox and I need to find users whose `firstname` Or `lastName` match the query.

This is my *tbl_users* table:

```
first_name     |    last_name

rocky          |   paul
____________________________
ranbir         |   kapoor
__________________________
rishi          |   kapoor
____________________________
ranbir         |   singh
__________________________
```

When I enter "ranbir" it will return 2 records, but when I enter "ranbir kapoor" it returns nothing.

My SQL query is:

```
select * from user where first_name like '%value%' OR last_name like '%value%'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show us the result of `DESCRIBE tbl_users`

Comment: @user3177586 Can you check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE
>       CONCAT(First_name, ' ', Last_name) LIKE '%ranbir kapoor%'

Use CONCAT(). http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat

example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/825e3/4/0